# Average function combined with userelationship

Tags: powerbi, average

I want to calculate the average repair time for the cases that have status=Finished and based on the inactive Finished date.

I created the following measure:

Measure average repair time = CALCULATE(AVERAGE( 'All cases'[Repair time (days)]),USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[Date],'All cases'[Finished Date]), 'All cases'[Status TEM only]="Finished")

I think that something is going wrong with it since the numbers that I get for the average repair time are a bit weird. Could you please help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all filters from Table 'All cases'

```
Measure average repair time = CALCULATE(AVERAGE( 'All cases'[Repair time (days)]),USERELATIONSHIP('Calendar'[Date],'All cases'[Finished Date]), FILTER(ALL('All cases'), 'All cases'[Status TEM only]="Finished"))
```